# Getting the ID of a GridView from a button Click contained within that gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have a situation where I have Multiple GridViews on a page GridView1 - GridView4.
All these GridViews have TextBoxes in the cells, I would like to run a calculation function only on the Column of the TextBox that was Clicked and on that particular GridView.

Example: A user clicks on a TextBox in Column 2 of GridView3 and changes a number value, the OnTextChange event of that particular TextBox should fire to run a calculation and total all the numbers of GridView3 Col2 in a footer label.

I searched and all the other suggestions I found assume you have only 1 grid and that you know what preset Column the calculation is done at IE a prices column, But I don't know what Column info a user will edit in any of my 4 GridViews.

I gave up and resolved to just running the calculation code on the Entire GridView, not just the column edited, but to do this I need to Get the GridView.ID of the Gridview containing the TextBox. Extensive serches came up with how to get the ID of the sender Item but not the GridView.ID that contains the sender.

If anyone can help with either situation, please do so, I would really appreciate it.

As Per the conversations below, I have edited this post to include the Edited answer provided by Tim in the hopes that others may learn from this code:

```
//This is working code
protected void textBox_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)txt.NamingContainer;
    GridView Grid = (GridView)gvRow.NamingContainer;

    // if you need the index of the column of the TextBox
    int colIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gvRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (gvRow.Cells[i] == txt.Parent)
        {
            colIndex = i;
            Msg.Text = "Col: "+colIndex.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }

    int gridNum = 0;
    switch (Grid.ID)
    {
        case "GridView1":
            gridNum = 1;
            break;

        case "GridView2":
            gridNum = 2;
            break;

        case "GridView3":
            gridNum = 3;
            break;

        case "GridView4":
            gridNum = 4;
            break;
    }

    Label ColTotal = (Label)Grid.FooterRow.FindControl("G" + gridNum + "TotalPP" + colIndex);

    double total = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid.Rows)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)row.FindControl(txt.ID);
        double d;
        if (double.TryParse(tb.Text, out d))
            total += d;
    }
    ColTotal.Text = total.ToString(); 
}
```

As you can see, according to the way the code is set up, the colIndex will help me find the footer label for each column and put it's total in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let all `TextBoxes` handle the same `TextChanged` event and use this <strike>(untested)</strike> code:

```
protected void textBox_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) sender;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow) txt.NamingContainer;
    GridView gv = (GridView) gvRow.NamingContainer;
    // if you need the index of the column of the TextBox
    // as commented below you're using .NET 2.0
    int colIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < gvRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (gvRow.Cells[i] == txt.Parent)
        {
            colIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    double total = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)row.FindControl(txt.ID);
        double d;
        if (double.TryParse(tb.Text, out d))
            total += d;
    }
    var tbFooter = (TextBox) gv.FooterRow.FindControl(txt.ID);
    tbFooter.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Of course assuming that all TextBoxes are in `TemplateFields` and the footer `TextBox` has the same ID. Remember to set `AutoPostback` to true if you want to postback immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the code and suggestion I will try his and see where it get's me. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: So far your solution seems to work best, but is there a way to get the columnIndex of the textBox that was changed? Such as `int ColIndex = ?? //The column index of the edited textbox?`
This is the last pice I would need to fix project.

Comment: Why do you need it? `FindControl` is the better way if you're using `TemplateFields`. If you need it for your footer-control you could also use FindControl when the ID is predictable(f.e. the same ID as the `TextBox` or the same suffix(f.e. `TextBox_4`, derive the "4").

Comment: @ragscoon: However, i've edited my answer to provide a way to get the colindex. But i don't like the `txt.Parent` approach in general(consider that the control would be nested in another container control).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need it because my GridViews have 27 columns and in the Template I have placed a footer label for each column IE: G1TotalPP1 the G1 corrisponds to the Grid 1 out of the 4 I have on the page and the PP1 is the column number. I'm finding the footer label for each column so I can put that columns total in each one:
`Label ColTotal = (Label)Grid.FooterRow.FindControl("G" + gridNum + "TotalPP" + ColIndex);

ColTotal.Text = total.ToString();
`
The GridNum varibale is assigned using a switch/case to see if I'm getting the TextBox trigger from G1, G2, etc..

Comment: I would like to post my code, but I don't think it can be done as a comment, I'm new to this forum so Im not up on how you would post code. It would be easy to show what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I added the colIndex part you suggested but I get an error, squiggle lines under "Enumerable" and the "i" variable "First(i", am I missing something?

Comment: @ragscoon: Note that i've edited my answer a little bit(`Enumerable.Range(0, gvRow.Cells.Count)`).   That's Linq, so you need to add `using System.Linq` and use at least .NET 3.5.

Comment: thanks for the code Tim, is there any way to get the column index of the TextBox using .Net 2.0, the project I have is 2.0 for compatability reasons, the client I'm doing this work for has not upgraded to 3.5 and many of the other components I've used are 2.0 compatable. Once again I really thank you for all your help.

Comment: @ragscoon: Of course, that's just a comfort function for a simple loop. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: :Thanks so much for the code, this looks like it will work perfectly for what I need, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

When TextChanged runs, sender is a reference to that textbox. You can use the parent property to find out what is the parent of that textbox.  If you chain parents together (something like `txt.Parent.Parent`, you'll eventually find the GridViewRow, and GridView objects.  Since you want to calculate the column, you'd have to find the cell that the control is in first, find the cell's index, then bubble up to the grid, loop through each row in that grid, and grab the values in the matching index.  I hope you don't have paging enabled, because that will skew the numbers (since they aren't all present).  Not an easy task, but possible.

From a performance perspective, you would get better performance with a client-side solution using JQuery or something else.

Comment: I had a simular idea at one point, I was trying to get it by finding the rowindex of the textbox control using: 

`protected void calculate_Col(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox ClickedBox = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ClickedBox.NamingContainer;
        int RowIdx = row.RowIndex;
        Msg.Text = RowIdx.ToString();
}`